# Make yaml-language-server validate OpenAPI nested Schema

Tags: yaml, openapi

The `yaml-language-server` has this features called [Nested schema references](https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server?tab=readme-ov-file#nested-schema-references) which allow you to reference a nested schema definition using a URL fragment.

Sadly, I could not get `yamlls` to validate a nested schema from the [Open API spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.1/schema.json).

For example, I would like that `yamlls` validates my parameter objects stored in a different file that the main `openapi.yaml`.

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/raw/main/schemas/v3.1/schema.json#/$defs/parameter
name: token
in: header
description: token to be passed as a header
required: true
schema:
  type: array
  items:
    type: integer
    format: int64
style: simple
```

This does does not work, `yamlls` just validates the document using the root schema, so the Open API schema.

It would be great if somebody could help me understand why this does not work and maybe provide me with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working like this:

Seems you need to use the `raw` version of the file because the uri you used is returning an html representation, not the raw json or yaml file

```yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/schemas/v3.1/schema.json#/$defs/parameter

name: test
in: headers
schema:
  type: string
required: true
```

```bash
Value is not accepted. Valid values: "query", "header", "path", "cookie".
```

Comment: Check the URL above again.

Comment: But what is weird is that is still complains about the `paths` not existing.

Comment: It seems to merge the root as well as the nested schema.

Comment: sounds like a bug with the yaml language server. Make an issue on the github repo