JSON schema validation with if-clause to choose different properties for same object
I like to write a JSON schema validation for this kind of yml
stages:

  - template: template-a.yml
    parameters:
      a-param1: abc
      a-param2: xy

  - template: template-b.yml
    parameters:
      b-param1: df
      b-param2: yz


So depending of the value of property "template", the property object "parameters" should have different properties.
I tried something like this, but if/then is not working for the object properties.
(if the property is on same level like "template" it's working)
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/azure-templates",
    "definitions": {
        "azure-templates": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "stages": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "anyOf": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/template-select"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "stages"
            ],
            "title": "azure-pipeline"
        },
        "template-params-a": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "template": {
                        "const": "template-a.yml"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "template"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "a-param1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "a-param2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "template-params-b": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "template": {
                        "const": "template-b.yml"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "template"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "b-param1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "b-param2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "template-select": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "template": {
                    "enum": [
                        "template-a.yml",
                        "template-b.yml"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/template-params-a",
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/template-params-b"
                }
            ],
            "required": [
                "template"
            ],
            "title": "Template"
        }
    }
}



the root $ref should be wrapped in an allOf. This behavior was later updated in Draft 2019-09 which allowed a root $ref and definitions(or any other keyword as a sibling) to be validated
the additionalProperties:false in your template-select schema is preventing the parameters from being used because in draft-07, allOf and additionalProperties:false don't play nicely together without some gymnastics in the schema. (if you really want to enforce this constraint, I've updated the schema)
I removed the anyOf in the items schema, it's not necessary with a single schema ref.

{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "allOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/azure-templates"
        }
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "azure-templates": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "stages": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/template-select"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "stages"
            ],
            "title": "azure-pipeline"
        },
        "template-params-a": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "template": {
                        "const": "template-a.yml"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "template"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "a-param1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "a-param2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "template-params-b": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "template": {
                        "const": "template-b.yml"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "template"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "b-param1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "b-param2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "template-select": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "template": {
                    "enum": [
                        "template-a.yml",
                        "template-b.yml"
                    ]
                }, 
                "parameters": true
            },
            "allOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/template-params-a"},
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/template-params-b"}
            ],
            "required": [
                "template", "parameters"
            ],
            "title": "Template"
        }
    }
}


Thanks Jeremy for the quick response. Unfortunately it's still not working for me. With that schema, it seems that just the last ref "$ref": "#/definitions/template-params-b" is used (intellij idea) and the parameters properties of template-b are also provided for template a.

opps.. the template-select allOf was malformed. It should be two separate subschemas there. I updated it.

Now, none property is provided for the parameters object :(

Can you explain what you mean by that?  If you're saying parameters:{} is passing the validation, that's correct based on your schema. You don't have any required keyword inside the parameters schema, so that means any property or no property is valid.  There are no constraints.

Sorry for being vage. I'm mainly looking for the autocomplete feature. So currently when I type something under parameters:{} I don't get any suggestions.

is this vscode? how have you setup your ide for intellisense/suggestions?

I tried it with Intellij Idea. So with vscode and a json file it is working as expected. But I didn't found way to use it for a yaml file yet.

Using VSC, it seems to suggest the properties correctly, based on the conditional validation defined.



Thanks Jeremy, this is working for me with VSCode and json files. Nevertheless I didn't found a way to use it for a yaml file yet. Should the schema work for yaml files as well ?

Yes  look here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950329/8564731

this also works with a json based schema file, and a yaml instance.  # yaml-language-server: $schema=./rules.json  assume you have a rules.json file in the same folder, it should recognize it and auto-complete should work. (i just tested it)

Thank you so munch Jeremy for your constantly help !! I would like to mark my questions as answered but currently I don't have enough reputation points.
